# Como fazer o valor de um TextInput inserido no componente A aparecer como valor de um outro TextInput num componente B? (react Native)

Tags: react-native, input, componentes

```
//exemplo componente A (fica numa pasta diferente do componente B)
...
const [carro1, setCarro1] = useState('');
<View>
//valor a ser repetido no TextInput do componente B
   <TextInput
       placeholder = "carro1"
       onChangeText = {setCarro1}
       value = {carro1}
   />
</View>
...

//exemplo componente B (fica numa pasta diferente do componente A)
...
<View>
//onde preciso que o valor do TextInput do componente A apareça
   <TextInput
       placeholder = "carro"
   />
</View>
...
```

Comment: Considerando que o state que você quer compartilhar está definido no componente pai, é só você passar o valor dele como prop para os dois componentes filhos. Para o componente em que haverá digitação, você passa também a função setter. Se houvesse uma hierarquia maior de componentes, o mais adequado seria usar `useContext` ou fazer um book personalizado.

Comment: useContext, é exatamente isso o que eu precisava, obrigado pela resposta amigo!